# Understanding lm and environment

Tags: r, lm

I'm executing `lm()` with arguments `formula`, `data`, `na.action`, and `weights`. My weights are stored in a numeric variable.

- When I specify formula as a character (i.e. `formula = "Response~0+."`), I get an error that weights is not of the proper length (even though it is).
- When I specify formula without the quotes (i.e. `formula = Response~0+.`), the function works fine.

I stumbled upon this sentence in the `lm()` documentation:

> All of weights, subset and offset are evaluated in the same way as variables in formula, that is first in data and then in the environment of formula.

This is difficult for me to interpret, but I sense that it contains the answer to my question.

Comment: What makes you think the formula argument needs to be quoted?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example?  I'm curious if the problem is in match.call().

Comment: @Dirk is correct: why quote the formula?

Comment: Nothing specifically makes me think that.  Clearly it can be quoted because it works in some cases.  Clearly it can be not quoted because it works in some cases.  I'm trying to understand the difference.

Comment: Iterator - why not?  I'm not making a case for quoting or not quoting, i'm just trying to understand the difference.  I provided a sentence from the lm documentation which I think holds the key.  Something do with the environment...I just can't figure it out

Comment: Iterator - I can repro this in my own code, but its too large to post.  I can get the debugger to break on a line that will fail with quotes and pass without quotes around formula.  I'm having trouble distilling that into a simple example that will repro.  That's why I posted the sentence from the lm documentation and hoping to have a more general conversation about the difference between quoting and not quoting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This has nothing to do with the real problem you have, [@DWin has addressed that, as have commentators on your Q] but is by way of explanation of the part of the documentation you quote)

The quoted help information means that the same process is used to find the variables/objects references in a model formula as is used to find variables/objects supplied to the arguments weights, subset etc.

R looks for for the objects referenced in the formula and by arguments weights, subset, and offset, first in the data object and then in the environment of the formula (which is usually the global environment during interactive use).

The reason why the docs mention this explicitly is because `lm()` as with many R functions that employ model-formula interfaces use the so-called standard *non-standard* evaluation. The up-shot is that say one supplies `weights = foo`, R won't necessarily look for object `foo` in evaluating the argument. Instead, it will look for an object with the name `foo` in the object supplied to the `data` argument, and if it doesn't find it there, then in the environment attached to the model formula, which as mentioned, doesn't always have to be the global environment.

Comment: Gavin, I think you have answered all my question.  DWin's answer is a good explanation of the formula class, but doesn't explain why character formula works.  I suspect that character formula is being coerced into a formula object by lm.  In that case, the environment of the formula is the lm frame, not the parent/calling frame.  A failure can occur with character formula when R goes looking for objects referenced in the formula that are not found in the data object (the process you called out).  These objects are guaranteed to be missing because the environment is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

When you construct an argument that is intended to be a formula, the parser "tries it out". It "expects" the argument to be a language call in the R sense. It does not expect it to be a character string delimited by quotes. That is why you will see people constructing formula arguments with paste(.) but then finishing them off by putting the strings or more correctly "character object" as an argument to as.formula(). What gets returned has been given a class of "formula" and a mode of "call":

```
> class( as.formula("Y ~ x") )
[1] "formula"
> mode( as.formula("Y ~ x") )
[1] "call"s
> class( "Y ~ x")
[1] "character"
> mode( "Y ~ x")
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Does it matter when I call `as.formula`, that is, `f <- as.formula(.); lm(f, ...)` versus `lm(as.formula(f),...)`, especially regarding the environment that will be used for `lm`?

Comment: Don't think so. Try it out: `dat <- data.frame(foo = 1:10, bar = runif(10)); environment(f <- as.formula(foo ~ bar); environment(formula(lm(f, data = dat))); environment(formula(lm(foo ~ bar, data = dat)))`

Comment: Actually I think it does. I have had instances where the "in-place" strategy failed but the calc-first strategy succeeded. I was surprised since it seemed to violate the functional paradigm.

Comment: @DWin Evidence? ;-) Seriously tho - can you recall if the problem was during interactive usage or when writing functions and wrappers? I can well believe the will be differences when writing your own functions and wrappers to functions that use formulae. In normal, interactive use I think things are simpler.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: I will try to post evidence. My memory is that this occurs in interactive sessions, but my memory has proved faulty at many times in the past. I'm just too busy at the moment to even try to construct a reproducible example

Comment: I seem to remember a difference as well (hence my question), though have never taken the time to try to figure out when.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: So far I have not been able to replicate with a simple call at the command line, so maybe I was composing a function at the command line and the environment issue raised its inscrutable head.

Comment: @DWin thanks for the update. Genuinely interested if you do think of something or have a brain wave.