# anova test fails on lme fits created with pasted formula

Tags: r

I often specify the formula argument to model fitting functions like `lm` or `lme` by pasting together the parts I need, as in @DWin's answer to this question: [Understanding lm and environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877534/understanding-lm-and-environment/6878461#6878461).

In practice this looks like this:

```
library(nlme)
set.seed(5)
ns <- 5; ni <- 5; N <- ns*ni
d <- data.frame(y=rnorm(N),
                x1=rnorm(N),
                x2=factor(rep(1:ni, each=ns)),
                id=factor(rep(1:ns, ni)))

getm <- function(xs) {
  f <- paste("y ~", paste(xs, collapse="+"))
  lme(as.formula(f), random=~1|id, data=d, method="ML")
}
m1 <- getm("x1")
m2 <- getm(c("x1", "x2"))
```

However, with `lme` from the `nlme` package, comparing two models constructed in the way using `anova` doesn't work, because `anova.lme` looks at the saved formula argument to ensure that the models were fit on the same response, and the saved formula argument is simply `as.formula(f)`.  The error is:

```
> anova(m1, m2)
Error in inherits(object, "formula") : object 'f' not found
```

Here's what the `anova` command should do (refitting the models so that it works):

```
> m1 <- lme(y~x1, random=~1|id, data=d, method="ML")
> m2 <- lme(y~x1+x2, random=~1|id, data=d, method="ML")
> anova(m1, m2)
   Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
m1     1  4 76.83117 81.70667 -34.41558                        
m2     2  8 72.69195 82.44295 -28.34597 1 vs 2 12.13922  0.0163
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ben's answer works, but `do.call` provides the more general solution he wished for.

```
getm <- function(xs) {
    f <- as.formula(paste("y ~", paste(xs, collapse="+")))
    do.call("lme", args = list(f, random=~1|id, data=d, method="ML"))
}
```

It works because (by default) the arguments in `args =` are evaluated before being passed to lme.

Comment: yes, but ... (and this is not the question the OP asked) ... I'm really most curious about how `lme` (or some other independent function) should behave so that it can make use of formulas that have been constructed in other (no longer directly accessible) environments

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem.  Could you put it up as a question in its own right, with some code illustrating the situation?

Comment: @BenBolker: I want to know the answer to your question too.  Any success in formulating it well?

Comment: Using `data=as.name("d")` instead of `data=d` will store the call as `data=d` instead of storing a representation of the data frame; this is useful for both object size and reuse using `update`.

Comment: Here's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9161273/210673) that was solved using this method.

Comment: And [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14940094/210673).  Can you tell I found this answer super helpful?  Thanks again, @JoshO'Brien!

Comment: @Aaron -- Yeah, `do.call()` is a real power-tool isn't it? What's funny to me is that this here was my first post on SO and folk(s) are still finding it helpful. For yet another interesting application of `do.call()`, from just a couple of days ago, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837902/how-to-write-a-function-that-calls-a-function-that-calls-data-table/14838797#14838797).

Comment: @Aaron this is a fantastic addendum and really helpful for my situation. I noticed that there is still a significant slow-down for me when using `do.call()` which led me to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13924631/2352940) -- using `quote=T` results in quicker execution, and keeps the formula as is.

Comment: @Aaron Actually, I ran into a problem with `as.name('d')` when using `do.call()` inside `llply()` such that I couldn't get `do.call()` to see `d`. Maybe I'll post a follow up question about this.

Comment: @jflournoy: thanks for the updates; I'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: This solution helped in a related question :http://stackoverflow.com/a/35864123/1199289

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, this has been fixed for a little while now (OP's example fixed in package version 3.1.163, 2023, according to the [Changelog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/ChangeLog)).

---

Here's a hack that seems to work:

```
getm <- function(xs) {
  f <- paste("y ~", paste(xs, collapse="+"))
  m <- lme(as.formula(f), random=~1|id, data=d, method="ML")
  m$call$fixed <- eval(m$call$fixed)
  m
}
```

but I don't like it at all.  I would very much like to see a more principled answer to this question, because I run into this sort of problem all the time when trying to extend the `bbmle` package.

Comment: Maybe the 'real' solution is for `lme` to check how the formula was passed and make sure it's stored correctly using `eval` exactly as you've done?

Comment: maybe, but I'm not sure I know how to do that The Right Way. I don't know the correct incantation (nor even the logic, which is the real problem) to evaluate the formula in the correct environment when it may have been passed down through a chain of several calling functions ...

Comment: @Ben -- Based on [my question and answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395724/any-pitfalls-to-using-programatically-constructed-formulas/17458699?noredirect=1#comment25405098_17458699) and Aaron's helpful pointer back to here, I think I may have stumbled on "The Right Way". Replacing the body of `nlme:::formula.lme` (currently `eval(x$call$fixed)`) with `formula(terms(x))` seems like the better way to do this, and does fix the scoping issues that occasioned the OP's question. (I tested using `fixInNamespace("formula.lme", "nlme")` after which `anova(m1, m2)` 'just worked'.