# User defined function based on step() gives: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to build a function which wraps around the `ordiR2step()` function from the `vegan` package. This function is based on the `step()` function.

This is the code to that works perfectly well outside of a function:

```
    install.packages("vegan")
    require(vegan)
    data(mite) 
    data(mite.env) #explanatory variables
    mite.hel = decostand(mite, "hel") #response variable
    mod0 <- rda(mite.hel ~ 1, mite.env)  # Model with intercept only 
    mod1 <- rda(mite.hel ~ ., mite.env)  # Model with all explanatory variables
    step.res <- ordiR2step(mod0, scope = formula(mod1), direction="forward") 
    step.res$anova
```

However, if I try and wrap this into a function:

```
    forward <- function(X, Y) {
    intercept <- rda(X ~ 1, data = Y)  # Model with intercept only
    model <- rda(X ~ ., data = Y)  # Model with all explanatory variables
    # this is where debugging is stuck
    forStep <- ordiR2step(object=intercept, scope = formula(model), 
                    direction = "forward", trace = FALSE)
    list(forStep$anova)
    }
    forward(mite.hel, mite)
```

I get the following error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found`

I know some problems can arise when trying to wrap these types of functions, and these issues have been been discussed many times on stackoverflow and other places, such as [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg75827.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161273/use-stepaic-on-a-list-of-models) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601106/missing-object-error-when-using-step-within-a-user-defined-function). However, none of these solution seem to have worked properly.

From my understanding of this behaviour, the `step()` function, and by extension the `ordiR2step()`, cannot read from the environment defined within the function, but only from the work space environment, because if I define `X` before calling the function, everything works well. However this defeats the purpose, so I tried some proposed solutions such as:

```
    forward2 <- function(X, Y) {
    intercept <- do.call("rda",list(X ~ 1, data = Y))  
    model <- do.call("rda", list(X ~ ., data = Y))  
    forStep <- ordiR2step(object=intercept, scope = formula(model), 
                    direction = "forward", trace = FALSE)
    list(forStep$anova)
    }
    forward2(mite.hel, mite.env)
```

Same error... No dice... Any suggestions? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Without unpacking the innards of `ordiR2step()`, I don't think this is going to be possible. The error is being raised by `ordiParseFormula()` and the call to which is buried quite deeply in the call stack at that point. What I mean is, these functions were written to work interactively and bets are off when you then start embedding these in further functions. I will take a look at the offending function and see if we can't improve it to help. The issues is actually when `ordiParseFormula()` starts to parse the formula for the next model in the forward selection chain...

Comment: ...it is looking for an `X` in a few locations but not in the execution frame of your function `forward()`.

Comment: The call stack is pretty deep, indeed. It seems that `ordiParseformula(..., envdepth = 6)` will get the data (the default is `envdepth = 2`). The error is triggered when `update()` tries to change the model. There seems to be no way of changing the `envdepth` value. Perhaps you have some secret agenda, but for this particular task, there is no need to wrap these three commands within `forward()`: you can issue those directly and then the analysis runs with no problem.

Comment: It seems that with 2 vegan developers on the case, I am in good hands! Thanks for your comments here. Indeed, I do have a secret agenda, here I have only provided the simplest example to reproduce the error I am trying to circumvent. I am trying many different rda models that incorporate dbMEMs, and so its useful to automate the exploration and visualization of selected spatial structure. While I also tracked the error to `update()`, I loose track and can't even tell where/how `ordiParseformula()` is called... so I've reached the limit of my own debugging skills (which are quite humble).

Comment: Anyhow, I will take your word that I can't change the `envdepth` value, so for now I will just define the object in the global environment before running my function. If you do figure this one out though, I suspect there may be other grateful explorers that may try and wrap `ordistep()` for testing some cool applications of model selection with some other functions bundled up. Cheers and thanks for the help!