# Doesn’t work step function after glm only in dplyr procedure

Tags: r, dplyr, glm

I'm trying to run a stepwise regression using dplyr, but it results in the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : cannot coerce class ‘c("glm", "lm")’ to a data.frame
```

glm works well, but when the code tries to save the result of a step to a dataframe the error occurs.

I checked the class of function glm and function step are the same as "c(glm, lm)". But only step funcion doesn't work.

I tried several ways to fix this error, 
like do statement, map2 (passing data a data parameter) but nothing works.

more detail.. 
when I run this code :

```
...
  group_by(ITEM_CODE) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ glm(formula_full,family=gaussian(),na.action=na.omit,data=.x))
         ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

results like as follow.. here, glm returns c("glm", "lm")

```
> M_CODE     data       model 
> 0034019   <tibble>    <S3: glm>       
> 0040726   <tibble>    <S3: glm>           
> 0057446   <tibble>    <S3: glm>
```

I'm trying to add 'step' results at 4th column of this (next model column).

But when I try to run the next code (add stepm variable)

2nd code :

```
  group_by(ITEM_CODE) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ glm(formula_full,family=gaussian(),na.action=na.omit,data=.x))
        ,stepm = map(model, ~ step(.x, direction = "both", trace = 0)) # <-- Error point!
         ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

then error occur which I mentioned at first.

Actually, 
class(model) = class(stepm) = c("glm", "lm")
but only stepm doesn't accepted and dropped error..

So, I'm very confused.. 
Does anybody know about this problem..?

Thank u in advance

Comment: The error message seems fairly informative. You have not described the goals of this effort in sufficient detail to offer alternatives. AND you don't have an MCVE either. Fix both deficiencies if you desire further effort.

Comment: I'll offer the further advice that "stepwise" methods are thought by most R experts to be ill-conceived. The ease with which this statistical malfeasance is executed in SAS or SPSS is thought to be one of their major failings  ... along with excessive cost and lack of transparency in methods.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Oh, thank u for ur advice. I wrote again with more detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also confused by the cause of this error, but I got a clue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601106/missing-object-error-when-using-step-within-a-user-defined-function) and tried wrapping `glm` in `do.call`

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(101)
model_df <- tibble(label=c("a", "b", "c"),
model_data = list(tibble(y=rbinom(100,size=1,prob=0.5),
                x1=rnorm(100),
                x2=rnorm(100),
                x3=rnorm(100),
                x4=rnorm(100)),
         tibble(y=rbinom(100,size=1,prob=0.5),
                x1=rnorm(100),
                x2=rnorm(100),
                x3=rnorm(100),
                x4=rnorm(100)),
         tibble(y=rbinom(100,size=1,prob=0.5),
                x1=rnorm(100),
                x2=rnorm(100),
                x3=rnorm(100),
                x4=rnorm(100))))
model_df <- model_df %>%
    mutate(model = map(model_data, ~ do.call("glm", list(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4,
                       family = gaussian(),
                       na.action=na.omit,
                       data = .x)))) %>%
    mutate(stepm = map(model, ~ step(.x, direction = "both", scope=list(lower=.~1, upper=formula(.x)),
                                     trace = 0)))
model_df$stepm[[1]]
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = y ~ 1, family = structure(list(family = "gaussian", 
#>     link = "identity", linkfun = function (mu) 
...
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  
#>        0.54  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  99 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       24.84 
#> Residual Deviance: 24.84     AIC: 148.5
```

Comment: I don't know why my reply was erased but thank u so much for ur answer. 
It worked perfectly! Thank u again!

Comment: I encountered the same problem and your solution worked like a charm! May I further ask how I could specify `weights = ` in the `glm()` call? I tried to pass the name of the weight column in `model_data` (e.g., `wt`) to the call as `weights = wt` but it didn't work, prompting "object 'wt' not found" error.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today, the reason behind it was that I gave the to-be-fitted model the same name as an existing dataframe, so the class of this variable was mixed. The solution is really simple, just change the name of the model to avoid naming overlaps, you'll be good to go.