# R : Pass argument to glm inside an R function

Tags: r, function, glm

I am trying to get used to scoping issues in R. I'd like to call the function `glm()` inside a function but it does not work, apparently for scoping reasons I did not manage to fix with the functions `assign()` or `eval()`.

Here is a simplified version:

```
ao <- function (y, x, phi = seq (0,1,0.1), dataset, weights) {
    logLikvector <- rep(0,length(phi))  # vector of zeros to be replaced thereafter
    for (i in 1:length(phi)) {          # loop to use glm()   
        fit <- glm (y ~ x, data = dataset, family = binomial, weights = weights)         
        logLikvector[i] <- logLik(fit)      # get log likelihood
    }
    logLikvector
}
```

Now I want to use the function ao() on my dataset

```
    ao (y = Prop, x = Age, dataset = mydata, weights = Total)
```

This does not work, but the following works:

```
ao (y = mydata$Prop, x = mydata$Age, dataset = mydata, weights = mydata$Total)
```

Does anyone know what to do ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!!

Btw, here is how to replicate my problem with the dataset I am using

```
library("MASS")
data(menarche)
mydata <- menarche
mydata$Prop <- mydata$Menarche / mydata$Total
```

Comment: Thanks for the opportunity to try out a lesson I learned this morning on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution with substitute (@DWin suggestion).

```
function(y, x, dataset, weights){
  f <- substitute(glm(y~x, data=dataset, weights=weights, family=binomial))
  logLik(eval(f))
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Sobala ! I wouldn't have found it by myself easily as I am still at the beginning of the learning curve in R !

Answer (score 3):

```
ao <- function (x, y, phi = seq (0,1,0.1), dataset, weights) {
    logLikvector <- rep(0,length(phi))
    x <- dataset[,substitute(x)]
    y <- dataset[,substitute(y)]
    weights <- dataset[,substitute(weights)]
        for (i in 1:length(phi)) {          # loop to use glm()
        fit <- glm (y ~ x, data = dataset, family = binomial, weights = weights)
        logLikvector[i] <- logLik(fit)      # get log likelihood
    }
    return(logLikvector)
}



library("MASS")
data(menarche)
mydata <- menarche
mydata$Prop <- mydata$Menarche / mydata$Total
ao(y = "Prop",x = "Age", dataset = mydata, weights = "Total")


[1] -55.37763 -55.37763 -55.37763 -55.37763 -55.37763 -55.37763
 [7] -55.37763 -55.37763 -55.37763 -55.37763 -55.37763
```

Comment: Instead of the slightly ugly `which(names(.)==arg` construction, why not use `substitute(arg)`? I tried it with your answer and it worked well in all three instances for your otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: Maiasaura, thank you ! This works indeed and I agree with DWin that using substitute (arg) is lighter. Anyway I understand better this scoping principle now...

Comment: @DWin: `substitute(arg)` is a really nice way of doing things like this within functions.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest creating the formula with `paste` and calling the function with `do.call`.

```
ao <- function (y, x, phi = seq (0,1,0.1), dataset, weights) {
  logLikvector <- rep(0,length(phi))  # vector of zeros to be replaced thereafter
  for (i in 1:length(phi)) {          # loop to use glm()
    f <- as.formula(paste(y, x, sep="~"))
    fit <- do.call("glm", list(formula=f, data=as.name(dataset), 
                   family="binomial", weights=as.name(weights)))
    logLikvector[i] <- logLik(fit)      # get log likelihood
  }
  logLikvector
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
ao("Prop", "Age", dataset="mydata", weights="Total")
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668846/210673 for more details.

Comment: Aaron, thanks to you too ! Your answer allowed me to learn about do.call. I will use substitute(arg) as suggested by DWin.

Comment: In this case I might too, `substitute(arg)` is a great way to do this in this case.  It actually does exactly the same thing as my solution except you can pass the parameters as names instead of characters (ie without quotes).