# Run glm.mids on a subset of imputed data from mice (R)

Tags: r, subset, r-mice

I get an error when I try to run `glm.mids` on a subset of a `mids` imputation object:

```
library(mice)
imp2 = mice(nhanes)
glm.mids( (hyp==2)~bmi+chl, data=imp2, subset=(age==1) )
```

gives the cryptic error message

```
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in"
```

even though the syntax works with regular `glm` on the original dataset:

```
glm( (hyp==2)~bmi+chl, data=nhanes, subset=(age==1) )
```

The documentation `?glm.mids` doesn't specifically address `subset` but says that you can pass additional parameters onto `glm`. If I can't use `subset` with `glm.mids`, is there a good way to subset the `mids` list object directly?

Comment: Try `with(data=imp2, exp=glm((hyp==2)~bmi+chl, family=binomial , subset=(age==1) ))`. I dont know why the subset doesn't work in `glm.mids`.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm not sure but i think the use of `...` in `glm.mids` code is not quite right (at least at current version of R). It works as you would expect if you alter the `glm` call (about half-way down `glm.mids`) with `eval(substitute(glm`. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858318/r-pass-argument-to-glm-inside-an-r-function

Comment: Will take a look. All this would make a great answer that I'd accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have taken the liberty of rewriting `glm.mids`. It is a bit kludgy. The issue seems to stem from the implicit nature by which attributes are passed into glm.

also see these post:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-November/041537.html

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Question-on-passing-the-subset-argument-to-an-lm-wrapper-td3009725.html

```
library(mice)

glm.mids=function (formula, family = gaussian, data, ...) 
{
  call <- match.call()
  if (!is.mids(data)) 
    stop("The data must have class mids")
  analyses <- as.list(1:data$m)
  for (i in 1:data$m) {
    data.i <- complete(data, i)
    analyses[[i]] <- do.call("glm",list(formula=quote(formula),family=quote(family),data=quote(data.i),...))
  }
  object <- list(call = call, call1 = data$call, nmis = data$nmis, 
                 analyses = analyses)
  oldClass(object) <- c("mira", "glm", "lm")
 return(object)
}

imp2 = mice(nhanes)
glm.mids( (hyp==2)~bmi+chl, data=imp2 ,subset=quote(age==1))
```

The only part that I rewrote was the glm function call within glm.mids `analyses[[i]] <- do.call("glm",list(formula=quote(formula),family=quote(family),data=quote(data.i),...))`

In the old version it read `analyses[[i]] <- glm(formula, family = family, data = data.i,...)`

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to use

```
with(data=imp2, exp=glm((hyp==2)~bmi+chl, family=binomial , subset=(age==1) ))
```

(I think) the problem in your question is the use of `...` within the `glm.mids` function. They are used in the function argument to allow “Additional parameters passed to glm”. However, when `...` are passed to the `glm` call in the `glm.mids` function they are not processed this way. In `?glm` the `...` are “For glm: arguments to be used to form the default control argument if it is not supplied directly.”. So the additional arguments will not work.

To see this, simplify the function

```
f1 <- function (formula, family = binomial, data, ...) 
{
 glm(formula, family = family, data = data, ...)
  }

f1(formula=((hyp==2)~bmi+chl), data=nhanes, subset=(age==2)) 
#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
#  ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

So the subset argument is not passed to the `glm` function call

Using the answer from [R : Pass argument to glm inside an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858318/r-pass-argument-to-glm-inside-an-r-function) we can slightly alter the function

```
f2 <- function (formula, family = binomial, data, ...) 
{
  eval(substitute(glm(formula, family = family, data = data, ...)))
}

# This now runs
f2(formula=((hyp==2)~bmi+chl), data=nhanes, subset=(age==2))

# check
glm((hyp==2)~bmi+chl, data=nhanes, family="binomial", subset=(age==2))
```

The use of `substitute` will substitute the arguments from the function environment (This needs more details - please feel free to update)