# Passing Argument to lm in R within Function

Tags: r, lm

I would like to able to call `lm` within a function and specify the `weights` variable as an argument passed to the outside function that is then passed to `lm`. Below is a reproducible example where the call works if it is made to `lm` outside of a function, but produces the error message `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'weightvar' not found` when called from within a wrapper function.

```
olswrapper <- function(form, weightvar, df){
  ols <- lm(formula(form), weights = weightvar, data = df)
  }

df <- mtcars

ols <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + qsec,  weights = gear, data = df)
summary(ols)

ols2 <- olswrapper(mpg ~ cyl + qsec,  weightvar = gear, df = df)
#Produces error: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'weightvar' not found"
```

Comment: What do you get when you type `gear`? Nothing, it's not defined globally, and your `olswrapper` doesn't know to look for it inside `df`. One way to make it work is passing `weightvar = "gear"` as a character, then in your `lm` call make `weights = df[weightvar]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R : Pass argument to glm inside an R function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858318/r-pass-argument-to-glm-inside-an-r-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on the comments, `gear` isn't defined globally. It works inside the stand-alone `lm` call as you specify the data you are using, so `lm` knows to take `gear` from `df`.

Howver, `gear` itself doesn't exist outside that stand-alone `lm` function. This is shown by the output of `gear`

```
> gear
Error: object 'gear' not found
```

You can pass the `gear` into the function using `df$gear`

```
weightvar <- df$gear
ols <- olswrapper(mpg ~ cyl + qsec, weightvar , df = df)
```

Comment: Why does this behave differently than passing `df$gear` directly to the wrapper (which produces the same error)?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late on this, but I believe the previous explanation is incomplete. Declaring `weightvar <- df$gear` and then passing it in to the function only works because you use `weightvar` as the name for your weight argument. This is just using `weightvar` as a global variable. That's why `df$gear` doesn't work directly. It also doesn't work if you use any name except `weightvar`.

The reason why it doesn't work is that lm looks for data in two places: the dataframe argument (if specified), and the environment of your formula. In this case, your formula's environment is `R_GlobalEnv`. (You can test this by running `print(str(form))` from inside `olswrapper`). Thus, `lm` will only look in the global environment and in `df`, not the function environment.

edit: In the `lm` documentation the description of the data argument says:
"an optional data frame, list or environment (or object coercible by as.data.frame to a data frame) containing the variables in the model. **If not found in data, the variables are taken from environment(formula)**, typically the environment from which lm is called."

A quick workaround is to say `environment(form) <- environment()` to change your formula's environment. This won't cause any problems because the data in the formula is in the data frame you specify.

Answer (score 2):

`eval(substitute(...))` inside a body of a function allows us to employ non-standard evaluation

```
df <- mtcars
olswrapper <- function(form, weightvar, df)
  eval(substitute(ols <- lm(formula(form), weights = weightvar, data = df)))
  summary(ols)

olswrapper(mpg ~ cyl + qsec,  weightvar = gear, df = df)
```

More here:
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html