# In R, how to use update() dynamically?

Tags: r, lm

In R I often need to cycle through a list of `lm` type objects (e.g. `glm`, `lme`, `clm`) and update them with a new formula or other arguments. I do this using `lapply()` because it returns them in the same list format with names intact, so I can continue the process.

Sometimes the argument I pass is dynamic and varies for each model. For example,

```
lapply(names(mylist) function(ii) {
  jj<-myotherlist[[ii]]; 
  update(mylist[[ii]],.~.+jj)
})
```

where `jj` is a term that gets added to each model in the list, and is defined in some other list on a per-model basis.

Let's say the intended result formula for a particular model was supposed to be `y~a+b+c`. Instead of that, the call object inside the resulting `lm` object contains `y~a+b+jj`. So, in some circumstances the resulting `lm` object behaves normally, but whenever the formula needs to be evaluated, it errors out because `jj` is long gone. Is there a recommended way to either force `update()` to expand all the variables among its arguments when it writes the `call` object in its output or to force functions that use the `call` object to evaluate the call in the `lm` object's internal context instead of the global context, so that at least I can stuff the new variables into the `model` or `data` object that `lm` style objects typically contain?

AND, what if the part that gets updated with a dynamic variable *is* the data argument? E.g.:

```
data=cbind(sharedByAllModels,y=kk)
```

...where `kk` is unique to the current model (perhaps some kind of aggregation of certain columns in the sharedByAllModels dataframe).

Answer (score 3):

Answering your main question, you can use `bquote()` to control which parts of the updating formula object (namely those within `.()`) get evaluated.

```
mylist <- list(y ~ a + b, y ~ A + B)
myotherlist <- list("c", "C")

lapply(1:2, function(ii) {
    jj <- as.name(myotherlist[[ii]])
    update(mylist[[ii]], bquote(. ~ . + .(jj)))})
# [[1]]
# y ~ a + b + c
# 
# [[2]]
# y ~ A + B + C
```

Alternatively, use `substitute()` in a similar fashion:

```
lapply(1:2, function(ii) {
      jj <- as.name(myotherlist[[ii]])
      update(mylist[[ii]], substitute(. ~ . + jj))
      })
# [[1]]
# y ~ a + b + c
# 
# [[2]]
# y ~ A + B + C
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `do.call`, which evaluates its arguments before execution.  See [anova test fails on lme fits created with pasted formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7666807/210673).