# Proper method to append to a formula where both formula and stuff to be appended are arguments

Tags: r, formula

I've done a fair amount of reading here on SO and learned that I should generally avoid manipulation of `formula objects` as strings, but I haven't quite found how to do this in a safe manner:

```
tf <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL, groups = NULL, ...) {
# Arguments are unquoted and in the typical form for lm etc
# Do some plotting with lattice using formula & groups (works, not shown)
# Append 'groups' to 'formula':
# Change y ~ x as passed in argument 'formula' to
# y ~ x * gr where gr is the argument 'groups' with
# scoping so it will be understood by aov
new_formula <- y ~ x * gr
# Now do some anova (could do if formula were right)
model <- aov(formula = new_formula, data = data)
# And print the aov table on the plot (can do)
print(summary(model)) # this will do for testing
}
```

Perhaps the closest I came was to use `reformulate` but that only gives `+` on the RHS, not `*`.  I want to use the function like this:

```
p <- tf(carat ~ color, groups = clarity, data = diamonds)
```

and have the aov results for carat ~ color * clarity. Thanks in Advance.

**Solution**

Here is a working version based on @Aaron's comment which demonstrates what's happening:

```
tf <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL, groups = NULL, ...) {
print(deparse(substitute(groups)))
f <- paste(".~.*", deparse(substitute(groups)))
new_formula <- update.formula(formula, f)
print(new_formula)
model <- aov(formula = new_formula, data = data)
print(summary(model))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think update.formula can solve your problem, but I've had trouble with update within function calls.  It will work as I've coded it below, but note that I'm passing the column to group, not the variable name.  You then add that column to the function dataset, then update works.

I also don't know if it's doing exactly what you want in the second equation, but take a look at the help file for update.formula and mess around with it a bit.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/update.formula.html

```
tf <- function(formula,groups,d){
  d$groups=groups
  newForm = update(formula,~.*groups)
  mod = lm(newForm,data=d)
}

dat  = data.frame(carat=rnorm(10,0,1),color=rnorm(10,0,1),color2=rnorm(10,0,1),clarity=rnorm(10,0,1))
m = tf(carat~color,dat$clarity,d=dat)
m2 = tf(carat~color+color2,dat$clarity,d=dat)

tf2 <- function(formula, group, d) {
  f <- paste(".~.*", deparse(substitute(group)))
  newForm <- update.formula(formula, f)
  lm(newForm, data=d)
}
mA = tf2(carat~color,clarity,d=dat)
m2A = tf2(carat~color+color2,clarity,d=dat)
```

EDIT:
As @Aaron pointed out, it's `deparse` and `substitute` that solve my problem: I've added `tf2` as the better option to the code example so you can see how both work.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @slammaster I think I may have had the same problems with `update.formula` inside a function!  For the lattice part of the call, I have to have the groups argument be an unquoted name of something in the data frame, so I can't use 'dat$clarity', I would have to use just 'clarity' as the argument.  So the `lm` or `aov` call has to work the same way after appending groups.

Comment: Try giving update a character string (formatting bad because in a comment, sorry...): tf <- function(formula, group, d) {
  f <- paste(".~.*", deparse(substitute(group)));
  lm(update.formula(formula, f), data=d)
}

Comment: @Aaron: Should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @Aaron Please make it an answer so I can accept it.  You are more skilled in the dark arts than I!  Thanks.  Bryan

Comment: Perhaps it should have been an answer, but it felt like a minor tweak to @slammaster's answer, who came up with the basic idea.  Perhaps slammaster would be willing to edit to include the tweak, and then you can accept this one?

Comment: In my mind it is the `deparse(substitute(groups))` that is the key magic that keeps it completely programmatic and general.  I'll let it sit a while longer before accepting something.

Answer (score 0):

One technique I use when I have trouble with scoping and calling functions within functions is to pass the parameters as strings and then construct the call within the function from those strings.  Here's what that would look like here.

```
tf <- function(formula, data, groups) {
  f <- paste(".~.*", groups)
  m <- eval(call("aov", update.formula(as.formula(formula), f), data = as.name(data)))
  summary(m)
}

tf("mpg~vs", "mtcars", "am")
```

See this answer to one of my previous questions for another example of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668846/210673.

Also see this answer to the sister question of this one, where I suggest something similar for use with `xyplot`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14858661/210673

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions and links.  I have working versions of my functions that take quoted names as arguments using methods similar to what you illustrate.  For some reason I got it into my head to convert to a more 'official' or slicker formula interface, which led me into this quagmire!  I'll emerge more knowledgeable in the long run, but it was much more work than I thought when I began.  Thanks again.

Comment: My answer here may also be useful to future searchers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14940094/210673