# Trouble passing on an argument to function within own function

Tags: r, function, environment, argument-passing

I am writing a function in which I want to pass some arguments to the crrstep-function ('crrstep' package), but I encountered a problem: somehow the argument 'event' in my function is not recognized when I enter it in crrstep. I guess that  crrstep looks in a different environment than the one I want it to look, but even after hours of searching for solutions on the web, I cannot seem to figure out how to solve this (I am quite inexperienced in programming..). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is some simulation data (adjusted example from crrstep-documentation) and an  example of my code:

```
n <- 500
ftime <- rexp(n)
fstatus <- sample(0:2,n,replace=TRUE)
testdata <- matrix(runif(8*n),nrow=n)
testdata <- cbind(ftime,fstatus,testdata)
dimnames(testdata)[[2]] <- c('ftime','fstatus','x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6','x7','x8')
testdata <- as.data.frame(testdata)
formula1 <- ftime ~ 1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8
rm(fstatus,ftime,n)

test.fun <- function(x,data,event){
require(crrstep)
select.mod<- crrstep(formula=x,,etype=event, failcode=1, cencode=0,data=data, 
                   direction = "backward", criterion = "AIC", crr.object = TRUE, 
                   trace = FALSE)
#Rest of function omitted for now
print(select.mod)
}

#Test
test.fun(x=formula1,data=testdata,event=fstatus) 
#I get: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'event' not found"
```

Many thanks!
Rob

Comment: The problem is that you `rm(fstatus)` before passing it as `event` parameter to your function...

Comment: Hi juba, before I remove fstatus I added it to the testdata, which I then use in my function as the 'data' argument. I thought that crrstep would look for the 'event' in 'data' (which I also pass on to crrstep), but somehow it doesn't..

Comment: then you should use `etype=data[,event]` in your `crrstep()` call, and pass the fstatus argument as a string : `event="fstatus"`.

Comment: When I enter it like this:`test.fun <- function(x,data,event){
  require(crrstep)
  select.mod<- crrstep(formula=x,,etype=data[,event], failcode=1, cencode=0,data=data, 
                       direction = "backward", criterion = "AIC", crr.object = TRUE, 
                       trace = TRUE)
    print(select.mod)
}

test.fun(x=formula1,data=testdata,event="fstatus")` I still get an error: Error in '[.data.frame'(data, , event) : object 'event' not found

Comment: These two recent questions are related, and may also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14784302/210673 http://stackoverflow.com/q/14839689/210673

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calling functions within functions that depend on evaluating names within a data frame, I use `do.call`, which evaluates its arguments before passing to the function and so makes both debugging and writing the code simpler, and I feel like I can be more sure about what it's doing.  (For debugging, just use `call` instead of `do.call`, which will show what the function will try to run; the syntax is also a little different so when doing this remove the list structure within the call as well.)

(Credit to Josh O'Brien's answer here for this idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668846/210673)

In this case, it would look like this:

```
test.fun <- function(x, data, event){
  require(crrstep)
  select.mod <- do.call("crrstep", 
         list(formula=x, etype=substitute(event), failcode=1, cencode=0,
              data=as.name("data"), direction = "backward", criterion = "AIC", 
              crr.object = TRUE, trace = FALSE))
  print(select.mod)
}

test.fun(x=formula1, data=testdata, event=fstatus)
```

The `substitute(event)` tells it to use the name that was given to the function, not the name `event`.  The `as.name("data")` tells it to look for `data` within the function instead of passing the actual data frame.  Another option is `substitute(data)` which will look for the actual data frame you have.

### an example using `lm`

Here's an example of very similar behavior using `lm` and the `weights` argument:

Here's an example data set and the call to `lm`, not within another function.  I print the `call` element of the response to see what it actually did.

```
> set.seed(5)
> dd <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=round(rnorm(10,mean=10),1), z=round(runif(10,1,4),1))
> lm(y~x, weights=z, data=dd)$call
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = dd, weights = z)
```

The natural way, which doesn't work because it's looking for `w` in the data frame:

```
> f1 <- function(f,w,d){
+   lm(formula=f,weights=w, data=d)
+ }
> f1(y~x, z, dd)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'w' not found
```

One can build the call with strings; this is a little more straightforward:

```
> f2 <- function(f,w,d){
+   do.call("lm", list(formula=as.formula(f), weights=as.name(w), data=as.name(d)))
+ }
> f2("y~x", "z", "dd")$call
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = dd, weights = z)
```

Or one can use `substitute`; here I'm calling the function on my actual data set `dd`, not the `d` within the function.  This might be useful later if I want to use `update`.

```
> f3 <- function(f,w,d){
+   do.call("lm", list(formula=f, weights=substitute(w), data=substitute(d)))
+ }
> f3(y~x, z, dd)$call
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = dd, weights = z)
```

But I could also use `d` within the function; this time notice that `data = d` in the call instead of `data = dd`.

```
> f4 <- function(f,w,d){
+   do.call("lm", list(formula=f, weights=substitute(w), data=as.name("d")))
+ }
> f4(y~x, z, dd)$call
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d, weights = z)
```

It works to put in the actual data frame as well, but the call is longer.  This however, might be desired if you're changing the data frame programatically before each call and want to have a record of what that data frame is.  (My preference, though, would be to save that data frame in a more explicit way, if you really do want it later.)

```
> f5 <- function(f,w,d){
+   do.call("lm", list(formula=f, weights=substitute(w), data=d))
+ }
> f5(y~x, z, dd)$call
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = list(x = 1:10, y = c(9.2, 11.4, 8.7, 
10.1, 11.7, 9.4, 9.5, 9.4, 9.7, 10.1), z = c(3.7, 3.2, 1.6, 1.7, 
1.4, 2.4, 2.3, 3.9, 1.4, 3.9)), weights = z)
```

One more to show that you can't just use `substitute` without `do.call` as the `substitute` is executed within the call to `lm`.

```
> f6 <- function(f,w,d){
+   lm(formula=f,weights=substitute(w), data=d)
+ }
> f6(y~x, z, dd)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = f, data = d, weights = substitute(w),  : 
  invalid type (symbol) for variable '(weights)'
```

Comment: @aaron This is extremely interesting, thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. But now I've got a headache :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand why, but it seems to fail if you pass your `etype` argument as an indexed data frame. However it seems to work if you create the vector beforehand :

```
test.fun <- function(x,data,event){
  require(crrstep)
  etype <- data[,event]
  select.mod<- crrstep(formula=x,data=data,etype=etype, failcode=1, cencode=0, 
                   direction = "backward", criterion = "AIC", crr.object = TRUE, 
                   trace = FALSE)
#Rest of function omitted for now
print(select.mod)
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, it didn't seem to work for me; I still get the `Error in '[.data.frame'(data, , event) : object 'event' not found` message.