# error object not found when calling glmulti within a function

Tags: r, function

I'm having trouble to use the package glmulti within my own function.

The code below is a simplified example that reproduces the error:
Error: object 'poplrun' not found

Which is the `data.frame` created within the function.
In the second example, it doesn't find the argument l.

I think the problem is related to the environment where glmulti is called. I found this post

[Trouble passing on an argument to function within own function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933804/trouble-passing-on-an-argument-to-function-within-own-function)

and tried to use `do.call` with `substitute(poplrun)` or `as.name("poplrun")` but clearly I'm missing something because it didn't work. I have also found this post 
[Object not found error when passing model formula to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218196/object-not-found-error-when-passing-model-formula-to-another-function)

and tried to identify the environment within the formula (as you can see in my first example) but that one too doesn't work.
I would really appreciate any help with this since it is now two days that I'm trying to solve this puzzle...

Thanks heaps!

## Example 1

```
    set.seed(5)
    df1<-data.frame(Scenario=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=10), 
                   Iteration=rep(1:10, 2), V1=rnorm(n=20, mean=0.5, sd=0.1))
    LookUpT<-data.frame(Scenario=rep(LETTERS[1:5]), SV1=1:5, SV2=6:10 )
    InteractRun<- function (
      param="V1" , 
      SVs=c("SV1", "SV2"),
      ic="aic",
      l=1 
      ) {
         poplrun<-df1
         require(plyr)
         poplrun<- join(poplrun, LookUpT, by = 'Scenario', type="left")
         xs<-paste(SVs, collapse="*") 
         .env<-environment() 
         formula<-as.formula(paste0(param, "~", xs), env=.env)
         require(betareg)
         require(glmulti)
         cand<-glmulti(formula, data=poplrun, method="d", level=l, 
         fitfunc=betareg,  na.action=na.omit)
         print(cand)
       }
       InteractRun()
```

## Example 2

```
    set.seed(5)
    df1<-data.frame(Scenario=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=10), Iteration=rep(1:10, 2), 
            V1=round(rnorm(n=20, mean=20, sd=2))) 
    LookUpT<-data.frame(Scenario=rep(LETTERS[1:5]), SV1=1:5, SV2=6:10 ) 
    InteractRun<- function (
    param="V1" , 
    SVs=c("SV1", "SV2"), 
    fam="poisson",
    ic="aic",
    l=1 
    ) {
       poplrun<-df1
       require(plyr)
       poplrun<- join(poplrun, LookUpT, by = 'Scenario', type="left")
       xs<-paste(SVs, collapse="*") 
       formula<-as.formula(paste0(param, "~", xs)) # set up formula to be used  
       glm1<-glm(data=poplrun, formula, family=fam, na.action=na.omit)
       require(glmulti)
       cand<-glmulti(glm1, method="d", level=l,  na.action=na.omit)
       print(cand)
      }
     InteractRun()
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to answer my own question... After a while, I figured out how to tackle the problem.
The correct call for glmulti is using `do.call` but there is no need for either `substitute()` or `as.name()`. In the example 1 the call should be: 
`cand <- do.call("glmulti", list(formula, data=poplrun, method="d", level=l, fitfunc=betareg, na.action=na.omit))`
and in example 2:
`cand <- do.call("glmulti", list(glm1, method="d", level=l, na.action=na.omit))`