# 'Object not found' when calling glmulti in own R-function

Tags: r

I would like to execute the following function:

```
library(glmulti)
jmra <- function(fname){
    mydata <- read.csv(fname)
    myvars <- c('X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6')
    formula <- paste('Y ~', paste(myvars, collapse='+'))
    glmulti.lm.out <- glmulti(formula, data=mydata, level=1, method="h", crit="aicc", confsetsize=50, plotty=F, report=F, fitfunction='lm')
    return(glmulti.lm.out)
}
test <- jmra('test.csv')
```

However, what I get is this error message:

> Error in glmulti(y = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 : object 'mydata' not found

Interestingly, everything works fine if the same code is outside of this function.
So what is happening here?

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was already provided here:
[error object not found when calling glmulti within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699673/error-object-not-found-when-calling-glmulti-within-a-function)

if "glmulti" is called like this, everything works as supposed to:

```
glmulti.lm.out<- do.call("glmulti", list(formula, data=mydata, level=1, method="h", crit="aicc", confsetsize=50, plotty=F, report=F, fitfunction='lm'))
```

Comment: I think you should send an email to the maintainer, this seems to be a bug.