# passing data.frame columns to function with data.table

Tags: r, function, data.table

I tried to write a fuction with data.table and here's an example about the idea:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:6, y=6:1, z= rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 2))
func <- function(q){
    o <- setDT(d)[, list(maxi = max(q)), by = z]
}
func(x)
```

the returned error said object x can't be found. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933804/trouble-passing-on-an-argument-to-function-within-own-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function), tried do.call and data.frame selection, with no good result:

```
o <- setDT(d)[, maxi = do.call('max', list(q)), by = z]
o <- setDT(d)[, maxi = do.call('max', list(d$q)), by = z]
o <- setDT(d)[, list(maxi = max(d[,q])), by = z]
```

it returned "unused argument", "object not found", or "invalid 'type' (closure) of argument". Am I following the previous answers wrong or data.table needs some special tuning? To see if this only happens with data.table, I also tested `o <- aggregate(d[, q] ~ z, d, max)` and the result was no good either. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's surprising about it? If `x` doesn't exist, how can one evaluate `func(x)`?

Comment: Change your function to `data.table(d)[, .(maxi = max(get(q))), by = z]` (you don't need `o <- ` ) and then run `func("x")`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677283/evaluating-both-column-name-and-the-target-value-within-j-expression-within-d) for some alternatives.

Comment: Or you can try use `lazyeval` package `func <- function(q){
q=lazy(q)
  o <- setDT(d)[, list(maxi = max(eval(q$expr))), by = z]
return(o)
}`