# Why does lazy evaluation "lose" a function argument?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, r-glue

I'm working with SQL and user input. So I'm using the `glue` library to handle with parameterized queries.

However, to keep things clean, I wrapped that all in a function:

```
safeQuery <- function(con, sql, ...) {  
  sql = glue_sql(sql, ..., .con=con)
  query <- dbSendQuery(con, sql)
  out <- dbFetch(query)
  dbClearResult(query)
  return(out)
}
```

So I just call that function with the connection, the SQL code and a list of parameters for that SQL code which `glue_sql` binds appropriately.

This works just fine.

Now, I have a specific SQL call which I use in one way or another quite often, but with varying parameters.

So I decided to create a function for that:

```
get_data <- function(con, params) {
  safeQuery(con,
            "SELECT *
             FROM foo
             WHERE bar IN ({vars*})",
            vars=params)
}
p = c(1, 2)
get_data(con, p)
```

So, the user data (in this case `c(1, 2)`) would be passed to `get_data`, which would pass it along with the SQL call to `safeQuery`, where `glue_sql` will take care of the bindings.

However, if I actually try to run `get_data`, I get an error

```
object 'params' not found
```

Googling and SO'ing has made it clear this has to do with R's lazy evaluation.

And indeed, changing `get_data` to

```
get_data <- function(con, params) {
  do.call("safeQuery",
          list(con,
               "SELECT *
                FROM foo
                WHERE bar IN ({vars*})",
               vars=params)
}
```

(as recommended by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14940094/2175231)) works just fine, since `do.call` evaluates the parameters in the list before sending them to `safeQuery`.

What I don't understand is why this is necessary in the first place. After all, the value of `params` isn't modified at any step along its way to `glue_sql`, so it should still be available.

The linked answer discusses the use of `substitute` (I also read [this R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/about-lazy-evaluation/) on the subject) to replace the argument's name with the caller's name for it (or with its actual value if the argument value was given directly), but that didn't work in my case. Modifying `get_data` to use `substitute`:

```
get_data <- function(con, params) {
  do.call("safeQuery",
          list(con,
               "SELECT *
                FROM foo
                WHERE bar IN ({vars*})",
               vars=substitute(params))
}
```

resulted in the following SQL from `glue_sql`:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE bar IN (params)
```

instead of the actual values of `params`. I couldn't try the same within `safeQuery` since the parameters are hidden in `...` and `substitute(...)` doesn't work. I tried.

I've also tried calling `force(params)` at the start of `get_data`, but that gave the same `object not found` error.

```
get_data <- function(con, params) {
  force(params)
  do.call("safeQuery",
          list(con,
               "SELECT *
                FROM foo
                WHERE bar IN ({vars*})",
               vars=params)
}
```

So, why does `params` get "lost" with the standard calls? Why does `do.call` work, but not `force(params)`? Is it possible to make this work using standard evaluation?

And I'm not going to lie: this experience has confused me about how to write my functions and handle their parameters (I'm considering only using `do.call` from now on). If tips can be given without over-extending the scope of this question, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: You never show how you call `get_data`, perhaps that might help me to understand what is going wrong. Can you include that?

Comment: @r2evans oops. Edited the question with an example of the call to get_data right after its first definition.

Comment: It works for me if your first line of `safeQuery` is instead `do.call(glue_sql, c(sql, list(...), .con=con))`. I'm not sure why (interesting question), but it works. (I recognize this is just a different view of your paragraph *"changing get_data to..."*.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear why this works, but it does.

```
safeQuery <- function(con, sql, ...) {
  dots  = list(...)
  dots
}
```

Then when you call `get_data("foo_con", params = 1:3)`, you get:

> ```
> $`vars`
> [1] 1 2 3
> ```

So now we have the argument in a named list, which means you should use `glue_data` (or `glue_data_sql`):

```
safeQuery <- function(con, sql, ...) {
  dots  = list(...)
  glue_data_sql(.x = dots, sql, .con=con)
  # More code...
}
```

Now when you call `get_data("foo_con", params = 1:3)`, you get:

> ```
> <SQL> SELECT *
> FROM foo
> WHERE bar IN (1, 2, 3)
> ```

---

## Alternate version:

The problem is about which environment the arguments are being evaluated in. One way to force this is to pass along the environment you want:

```
safeQuery <- function(con, sql, ..., .envir = parent.frame()) {
  dots  = list(...)
  glue_sql(sql, ..., .con=con, .envir = .envir)
  # More code...
}

get_data <- function(con, params) {

  env <- environment()

  safeQuery(con,
            "SELECT *
            FROM foo
            WHERE bar IN ({vars*})",
            vars=params, .envir = env)
}

get_data("foo_con", params = 1:3)
```

> ```
> <SQL> SELECT *
> FROM foo
> WHERE bar IN (1, 2, 3)
> ```

Comment: I don't have access to my computer right now, so can't check this myself. Looking at that last chunk, though, that doesn't look right. `glue_sql` should output a single SQL call which ends with `IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: @Wasabi you're right, I transposed the `*` when I was fiddling with the `get_data` function. It returns the correct output now.