# How to write a function that calls a function that calls data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

The package `data.table` has some special syntax that requires one to use expressions as the `i` and `j` arguments.

This has some implications for how one write functions that accept and pass arguments to data tables, as is explained really well in [section 1.16 of the FAQs](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf).

But I can't figure out how to take this one additional level.

Here is an example.  Say I want to write a wrapper function `foo()` that makes a specific summary of my data, and then a second wrapper `plotfoo()` that calls `foo()` and plots the result:

```
library(data.table)


foo <- function(data, by){
  by <- substitute(by)
  data[, .N, by=list(eval(by))]
}

DT <- data.table(mtcars)
foo(DT, gear)
```

OK, this works, because I get my tabulated results:

```
   by  N
1:  4 12
2:  3 15
3:  5  5
```

---

Now, I try to just the same when writing `plotfoo()` but I fail miserably:

```
plotfoo <- function(data, by){
  by <- substitute(by)
  foo(data, eval(by))
}
plotfoo(DT, gear)
```

But this time I get an error message:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

---

OK, so the `eval()` is causing a problem. Let's remove it:

```
plotfoo <- function(data, by){
  by <- substitute(by)
  foo(data, by)
}
plotfoo(DT, gear)
```

Oh no, I get a new error message:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, , .N, by = list(eval(by))) : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type symbol. Do not quote column names. Useage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

---

And here is where I remain stuck.

**Question:  How to write a function that calls a function that calls data.table?**

Comment: Not a solution, but if you remove `substitute(by)` and `eval` and pass `gear` as a character variable like `foo(DT, "gear")` then both works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work:

```
plotfoo <- function(data, by) {
  by <- substitute(by)
  do.call(foo, list(quote(data), by))
}

plotfoo(DT, gear)
#    by  N
# 1:  4 12
# 2:  3 15
# 3:  5  5
```

**Explanation:**

The problem is that your call to `foo()` in `plotfoo()` looks like one of the following:

```
foo(data, eval(by))
foo(data, by)
```

When `foo` processes those calls, it dutifully `substitute`s for the **second formal argument** (`by`) getting as `by`'s **value** the symbols `eval(by)` or `by`. But you want `by`'s value to be `gear`, as in the call `foo(data, gear)`.

`do.call()` solves this problem by evaluating the elements of its second argument before constructing the call that it then evaluates. As a result, when you pass it `by`, it evaluates it to its value (the symbol `gear`) before constructing a call that looks (essentially) like this:

```
foo(data, gear)
```

Comment: +1 This works very well, thank you, even for my implied but unstated requirement for passing on the `i` and `j` arguments.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be tieing yourself up in knots. This works:

```
library(data.table)
foo <- function(data, by){
  by <- by
  data[, .N, by=by]
}

DT <- data.table(mtcars)
foo(DT, 'gear')

plotfoo <- function(data, by){
  foo(data, by)
}
plotfoo(DT, 'gear')
```

And that method supports passing in character values:

```
> gg <- 'gear'
> plotfoo <- function(data, by){
+   foo(data, by)
+ }
> plotfoo(DT, gg)
   gear  N
1:    4 12
2:    3 15
3:    5  5
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I'm wondering what's the meaning of `by <- by` inside foo.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're quite right. I apologise, in my attempt to simplify my example, I removed the original problem of passing an argument to the `i` or `j`. I'm sorry - I'll edit my question.

Comment: @vodka: No particular meaning. Just left over from editing the original.

Comment: @Andrie: Did either Josh's or my answer get at the issues you were having with i, and j evaluation?

Comment: Yes, the solution by Josh works very well indeed, although I don't claim to understand it!

Comment: Heh, I will admit that one of my favorite functions was written with `do.call` after considerable mental pain trying other things. In some ways `do.call` is like a `paste0` in the "language sub-universe of R". At least that's the way I think of it.