# Wrapping data.table using an evaluated call in a package

Tags: r, expression, eval, environment, data.table

I'm trying to write a simple wrapper around `data.table` for split-apply-combine use (like `aggregate`, `ddply` etc.) in order to gain from `data.table`'s speed but not use its data structures or syntax. I have tried the following.

```
fold = function(df, by, ...)
{
    library(data.table)
    dt = data.table(df)
    dt = dt[, eval(substitute(list(...))), by]
    df = as.data.frame(dt)
    return(df)
}

a = data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), y=runif(6))
b = fold(a, "x", y_min=min(y), y_max=max(y))
print(a)
print(b)
```

This works fine when I put it in a script and `source` it, but when I put that function in a package, install it and try to use it, I get

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
Calls: fold -> [ -> [.data.table -> [.data.frame -> eval -> eval
```

What am I doing wrong, apart from trying this in general?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe worth checking [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837902/how-to-write-a-function-that-calls-a-function-that-calls-data-table)

Comment: Do you have `data.table` in your `Depends:` list?

Comment: @Andrie: No, I didn't and it does work once added. Why doesn't `Suggests:` and loading `data.table` in the function body work here?

Comment: @otsaw Good question. Because at the top of most `data.table` functions is a call to `data.table:::cedta` (Calling Environment Data.Table Aware). That needs you specifically Depend, Import, or, create `.datatable.aware=TRUE`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10529888/403310

Comment: You might also want to talk to @Hadley, who is/was working on something like this, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following comments, FAQ 6.9 answered this one :

> *FAQ 6.9 I have created a package that depends on data.table. How do I ensure my package is data.table-aware so that inheritance from data.frame works?*
>   You don't need to do anything special. Just include `data.table` in either the `Imports:` or `Depends:` field of your package's DESCRIPTION file.

Some technical detail of how inheritance from `data.frame` maintains full compatibility with `[.data.frame` is here :

[Using data.table package inside my own package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527072/using-data-table-package-inside-my-own-package)