# Performing multiple regression with purrr and R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, purrr

I'm trying to figure out how can I set up **purrr** to run several multiple regressions like the image below. As you will notice, this dataset describes an intervention program and we are analyzing this data using ANCOVA procedures (TIME 2 ~ TIME 1 + CONDITION).

```
om4g**TIME2**01 ~ om4g**TIME1**01 + CONDITION
```

example:

```
om4g201 ~ om4g01 + CONDITION
```

[image: Regression models]

Just in case someone want a reproducible code:

```
dataset <- data.frame(rest201=c(10,20,30,40),
                      rest101=c(5,10,20,24),
                      omgt201=c(40,10,20,10),
                      omgt101=c(10,20,10,05),
                      CONDITION=c(0,1))
lm(rest201~rest101+CONDITION, data=dataset)
lm(omgt201~omgt101+CONDITION, data=dataset)
```

I found just one similar question than mine here ([Making linear models in a for loop using R programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258278/making-linear-models-in-a-for-loop-using-r-programming)) but the answer was not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to @Roman's answer, here is how to do it using `map2` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

y_var = c("rest201", "omgt201")
x_var = list(c("rest101", "CONDITION"), c("omgt101", "CONDITION"))

map2(x_var, y_var, ~ lm(as.formula(paste(.y, "~", paste(.x, collapse = " + "))), data = dataset))
```

To get the summary table for each model, you can wrap each `lm` with `summary` and extract the `coefficients` table:

```
map2(x_var, y_var, ~ {
  lm(as.formula(paste(.y, "~", paste(.x, collapse = " + "))), data = dataset) %>%
    summary() %>%
    `$`("coefficients")
})
```

**Result:**

```
[[1]]
            Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 2.779097 0.76821670  3.617596 0.17169133
rest101     1.377672 0.04750594 29.000000 0.02194371
CONDITION   3.800475 0.72163694  5.266464 0.11945968

[[2]]
                 Estimate Std. Error       t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  3.000000e+01  16.666667  1.800000e+00 0.3228289
omgt101     -2.445145e-16   1.333333 -1.833859e-16 1.0000000
CONDITION   -2.000000e+01  14.529663 -1.376494e+00 0.3999753
```

Comment: Wow @useR, Amazing! Thanks much! That is what I was looking for! Could you please tell me how to report the significance of each predictor ?

Comment: Thanks much, @useR. Where I should click to accept your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a list of formulas for each model and use that to construct a model.

```
x <- c(101, 102, 103)
mdls <- sprintf("omg4g%s ~ om4g%s + CONDITION",
        as.character(x + 100), 
        as.character(x)
)

out <- sapply(mdls, FUN = function(x) {
  formula(x, data = latino_dataset)
})

$`omg4g201 ~ om4g101 + CONDITION`
omg4g201 ~ om4g101 + CONDITION
<environment: 0x0000000009aff7b8>

$`omg4g202 ~ om4g102 + CONDITION`
omg4g202 ~ om4g102 + CONDITION
<environment: 0x0000000009afda98>

$`omg4g203 ~ om4g103 + CONDITION`
omg4g203 ~ om4g103 + CONDITION
<environment: 0x00000000099b0828>
```

e.g.

```
sapply(out, FUN = lm)
```

Comment: Thanks much for your reply, @Roman Luštrik. I appreciate it! The code was almost 100%. I changed the last sentence to: sapply(out, FUN = lm, data=latino_dataset) (because R was returning an error). Unfortunately, the output is something like that: sapply(out, FUN = lm, data=latino_dataset)
              om4g201 ~ om4g101 + CONDITION
coefficients  Numeric,3
Could you please tell me how to display the summary instead this output. Thanks much again!

Comment: @Luis try adding `sapply(..., simplify = FALSE)` and you should get a list of the results.