# Explicit formula used in linear regression

Tags: r

I have a list of formulas, and I use `lapply` and `lm` to create a list of regression models. However, when I look at the `call` component of each linear model, instead of seeing the explicit formula, I see the name of the variable I parsed into the linear model. E.g. using the mtcars dataset:

```
temp_formula_list = list(as.formula(hp~1),as.formula(hp~cyl))
temp_fm_list = lapply(temp_formula_list, function(x) lm(data = mtcars, formula = x))
```

Then examining the `call` of `temp_fm_list[[2]]`:

```
temp_fm_list[[2]]$call
```

gives

```
lm(formula = x, data = mtcars)
```

when I would like it to explicitly give

```
lm(formula = hp~cyl, data = mtcars)
```

Comment: `do.call` can be very useful in this situation; see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/7668846/210673

Comment: Thanks. This looks almost like a duplicate of my question. I am guessing I should use `do.call("lm",args = list(formula = x, data=mtcars))` instead of `lm(data = mtcars, formula = x)` in the lapply.

Comment: This kind of works, except it also evaluates the mtcars data, leading to a very messy `call` component...

Comment: `do.call("lm",args = list(formula = x, data= quote(mtcars)))` will work as you wish.

Comment: thanks, the `quote` function was what I was looking for, while trying to fix this.

Comment: @Alex -- I've added that to my answer, for completeness.

Comment: Thanks, out of all these, the `do.call` option is probably the easiest to understand.

Comment: `as.name` works too (instead of `quote`); that's buried in the comments to the answer I linked to earlier

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do some simple computing on the language using `bquote` to construct your call.

```
 temp_fm_list = lapply(temp_formula_list, function(x) {
  lmc <- bquote( lm(data = mtcars, formula = .(x)))
  eval(lmc)                                                      
  })
temp_fm_list
# Call:
#   lm(formula = hp ~ 1, data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  
# 146.7  
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = hp ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl  
# -51.05        31.96
```

Note that

```
function(x) do.call('lm', list(formula = x, data = quote(mtcars))
```

Would also work

---

### Other approaches....

Even with your original call you can recreate the formula from the `terms` object associated with the model

eg

```
x <- hp ~ cyl

lmo <- lm(formula = x, data = mtcars)

formula(lmo)
## hp ~ cyl

lmo$call 


# lm(formula = x, data = mtcars)
```

You  can  mess with this `call` object if you wish (although this is rather dangerous practice)

```
# for example

lmo$call$formula <- x
lmo$call 
##  lm(formula = hp ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

## however you can create rubbish here too
lmo$call$formula <- 'complete garbage'
lmo$call 
## lm(formula = "complete garbage", data = mtcars)

# but, being careful, you could use it appropriately
temp_fm_list = lapply(temp_formula_list, function(x) {
  oo <- lm(data = mtcars, formula = x)
  oo$call$formula <-x
  oo
})

temp_fm_list
# Call:
#   lm(formula = hp ~ 1, data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  
# 146.7  
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = hp ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          cyl  
# -51.05        31.96
```