# How can I pass an argument as a character to a function within a function?

Tags: r, lapply, lm

I'm trying to create a series of models based on subsets of different categories in my data. Instead of creating a bunch of individual model objects, I'm using `lapply()` to create a list of models based on subsets of every level of my category factor, like so:

```
test.data <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100), category=rep(c("A", "B"), 2))

run.individual.models <- function(x) {
  lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=test.data, subset=(category==x))
}

individual.models <- lapply(levels(test.data$category), FUN=run.individual.models)
individual.models

# [[1]]

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = test.data, subset = (category == 
#     x))

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1           x2  
#     0.10852     -0.09329      0.11365
# ....
```

This works fantastically, except the model call shows `subset = (category == x)` instead of `category == "A"`, etc. This makes it more difficult to use both for diagnostic purposes (it's hard to remember which model in the list corresponds to which category) and for functions like `predict()`.

Is there a way to substitute the actual character value of `x` into the `lm()` call so that the model doesn't use the raw `x` in the call?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754362/explicit-formula-used-in-linear-regression/15754430#15754430

Comment: The order is the same as in your `levels(test.data$category)`. Would it be acceptable to change list names to reflect that?

Comment: That fixes the first issue (making the list more human readable), but it still creates a bunch of models that are unusable by `predict()` outside of the list (i.e. the models can't stand alone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines of [Explicit formula used in linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754362/explicit-formula-used-in-linear-regression/15754430#15754430)

Use `bquote` to construct the call

```
run.individual.models <- function(x) {
  lmc <- bquote(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=test.data, subset=(category==.(x))))
  eval(lmc)
}

individual.models <- lapply(levels(test.data$category), FUN=run.individual.models)
individual.models

[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = test.data, subset = (category == 
    "A"))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
   -0.08434      0.05881      0.07695  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = test.data, subset = (category == 
    "B"))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
     0.1251      -0.1854      -0.1609
```