# Create lme object within a function

Tags: r, lm, nlme

**Background**

I am trying to fit a mixed model in a function based on some parameters. If I want to use `contrast` from `library(contrast)` I have to use a workaround, as `contrast` uses the `call` slot from the `lme` object to determine the `data`, `fixed` or `random` argument passed to `lme` in the function (cf. code). This is by the way not the case with an `lm` object.

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y1 = rnorm(100), y2 = rnorm(100),
                  grp = factor(sample(2, 100, replace = TRUE)))
```

**Code**

```
library(contrast)
library(nlme)
makeMixedModel1 <- function(resp, mdat = dat) {
   mF <- formula(paste(resp, "x", sep = "~"))
   mdat <- mdat[resp > 0, ]
   mod <- lme(mF, random = ~ 1 | grp, data = mdat)
   mC <- mod$call
   mC$fixed <- mF
   mC$data <- mdat
   mod$call <- mC
   mod
}

makeMixedModel2 <- function(resp, mdat = dat) {
   mF <- formula(paste(resp, "x", sep = "~"))
   mdat <- mdat[resp > 0, ]
   lme(mF, random = ~ 1 | grp, data = mdat)
}

mm1 <- makeMixedModel1("y1")
mm2 <- makeMixedModel2("y1")
contrast(mm1, list(x = 1)) ## works as expected
# lme model parameter contrast
# 
#   Contrast      S.E.      Lower     Upper    t df Pr(>|t|)
#  0.1613734 0.2169281 -0.2692255 0.5919722 0.74 96   0.4588

contrast(mm2, list(x = 1)) ## gives an error
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mF' not found
```

**Question**

I have tracked down the error to the part where `contrast` evaluates the `fixed`slot within the `call` slot of `mm2` whis equals to `mF` which is of course not known at the top level, as it was defined only inside my function `makeMixedModel2`. The workaround in `makeMixedModel1` remedies that by explicitely overwriting the respective slots in `call`.

Apparently, for `lm` objects this is solved in a smarter way, as there's no need to do the manual overwriting as `contrast` seems to evaulate all the parts within the right context though of course `mF` and `mdat` are not known either:

```
makeLinearModel <- function(resp, mdat = dat) {
   mF <- formula(paste(resp, "x", sep = "~"))
   mdat <- mdat[resp > 0, ]
   lm(mF, data = mdat)
}
contrast(makeLinearModel("y1"), list(x = 1))
```

So, I assume that `lm` stores the values of the `formula` and the `data` somewhere, such that in can be retrieved also at different environments.

I can live with my workaround, though it has some ugly side-effects as a `print(mm1)` shows all the data instead of a simple names. So my question is, whether there are some other strategies to get what I intend? Or do I have to write to the maintainer of `contrast` and ask him, whether he can change the code for `lme` objects such that hes does not rely anymore on the `call` slot, but tries to solve the issue otherwise (as it is done for the `lm`)?

Comment: I think this is may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666807/anova-test-fails-on-lme-fits-created-with-pasted-formula), with an answer showing how to do this via `do.call` (although with the same side effects as your solution, possibly).

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. The problem is not so much that I cannot solve it, the question was how to avoid the side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're fighting is just a buggy implementation of `contrast()` for `lme` objects.  I would contact the author to fix it (it may be a result of something recent changing with `nlme`).  But in the mean time you can avoid your side effects by implementing your workaround in the `contrast.lme()` function rather than in your model construction function:

```
contrast.lme <- function(fit, ...) {
   mC <- fit$call
   mC$fixed <- formula(fit) 
   mC$data <- fit$data
   fit$call <- mC

   library(nlme)
   contrast:::contrastCalc(fit, ...)
}
assignInNamespace("contrast.lme", contrast.lme, "contrast")

mm2 <- makeMixedModel2("y1")

contrast(mm2, list(x = 1))
```

Yields:

```
lme model parameter contrast

  Contrast      S.E.      Lower     Upper    t df Pr(>|t|)
 0.1613734 0.2169281 -0.2692255 0.5919722 0.74 96   0.4588
```

And:

```
print(mm2)
```

Yields:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: mdat 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -136.2472
  Fixed: mF 
(Intercept)           x 
 -0.1936347   0.3550081 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | grp
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:    0.131666 0.9365614

Number of Observations: 100
Number of Groups: 2
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed the trick and I learned also something new (`assignInNamespace`). More than worth the bounty :) Thx.

Comment: Heh, happy to help. This isn't likely in your case, but mucking around with functions inside package namespaces can cause some unintended consequences (i.e. if for some reason `contrastCalc()` re-calls `contrast.lme()` for example). But it is very useful occasionally, especially if you're testing minor changes and don't want to deal with the whole package's source.