# How do I use lm() from inside a function?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

It seems that calling `lm()` from within a function or via `lapply` screws up the `$call` associated with a fit. Minimal working example:

```
> library(MASS)
> dat <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y=1:100)
> dat <- within(dat, z <- x + log(y) + rnorm(100))
> fits <- lapply(list(z ~ x + y, z ~ x + log(y)), lm, dat)
> stepAIC(fits[[1]])               # <-- error when I try to use the fit in other functions
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "FUN"

> fits[[1]]$call
FUN(formula = X[[i]], data = ..1)  # Aha -- this must be why -- $call is screwed up
```

How do I resolve this problem and prevent the above error?

Comment: @coffeinjunky No, things are kept simple just for this toy example

Comment: Here's a similar question, for reference http://stackoverflow.com/q/7666807/210673

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to supply an anonymous function to `lapply`:

```
fits <- lapply(list(z ~ x + y, z ~ x + log(y)), 
                   function(f) lm(f, data = dat))
stepAIC(fits[[1]])
#works
```

Note that this (usually my preferred way to make scoping explicit) doesn't work because `DF` is not found by `stepAIC`:

```
fits <- lapply(list(z ~ x + y, z ~ x + log(y)), 
                   function(f, DF) lm(f, data = DF), DF = dat)
```

Note that stepwise regression [is a bad method anyway](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/11849).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative yould be to apply the `stepAIC` inside `lapply` directly:

```
 AICs <- lapply(list(z ~ x + y, z ~ x + log(y)), 
                function(x) stepAIC(lm(x,dat)))
```

This gives you a list of the output of `stepAIC` for all models.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this as the function in the lapply.  This produces nice looking formulas in `fits` showing the actual formula and `stepAIC` works:

```
fun <- function(fo) do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(dat)))
fits <- lapply(list(z ~ x + y, z ~ x + log(y)), fun)
```

giving:

```
> fits[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = z ~ x + y, data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x            y  
      2.154        1.031           NA  


> stepAIC(fits[[1]])
Start:  AIC=-3.34
z ~ x + y


Step:  AIC=-3.34
z ~ x

       Df Sum of Sq   RSS    AIC
<none>                 93  -3.34
- x     1     88600 88693 680.78

Call:
lm(formula = z ~ x, data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
      2.154        1.031
```