# Using column numbers not names in lm()

Tags: r, formula, lm

Instead of something like `lm(bp~height+age, data=mydata)` I would like to specify the columns by number, not name.

I tried `lm(mydata[[1]]~mydata[[2]]+mydata[[3]])` but the problem with this is that, in the fitted model, the coefficients are named `mydata[[2]]`, `mydata[[3]]` etc, whereas I would like them to have the real column names.

Perhaps this is a case of not having your cake and eating it, but if the experts could advise whether this is possible I would be grateful

Comment: You might get better answers if you give a slightly larger context for what you're trying to do: "what is the problem you are trying to solve"?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a large number of columns in a dataframe. I am fitting a linear model using a subset of these, using various techniques including stepwise selection. It will be convenient if I can refer to the columns by number when calling lm() but if possible I would like the model to show the column names.

Comment: I would paste together a formula based on the names, as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877534/understanding-lm-and-environment/6878461#6878461

Comment: If you come up with a good solution you're allowed (encouraged) to post an answer to your own question ...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
lm(
    as.formula(paste(colnames(mydata)[1], "~",
        paste(colnames(mydata)[c(2, 3)], collapse = "+"),
        sep = ""
    )),
    data=mydata
)
```

Instead of `c(2, 3)` you can use how many indices you want (no need for for loop).

Comment: missing a comma at the end of the third line?

Comment: Thanks, @Ben. Also, maybe using `as.formula` would be more robust, though not needed for `lm()` (but for other models do).

Comment: Thank you. This spells out what Ben Bolker suggested earlier, and works perfectly.

Comment: To make this completely foolproof I needed to add backticks around the column names because of special characters in the names: `paste('\`', colnames(mydata)[c(2,3)], '\`', sep = "", collapse = "+")`

Answer (score 2):

```
lm(mydata[,1] ~ ., mydata[-1])
```

The trick that I found in a course on R is to remove the response column, otherwise you get warning "essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable". I do not know why it works, it does not follow from documentation. Normally, we keep the response column in.

And a simplified version of the earlier answer by Tomas:

```
lm(
    as.formula(paste(colnames(mydata)[1], "~ .")),
    data=mydata
)
```